# Separate expression to strings

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this wildcard expression pattern and want to resolve to all possible combinations.

```
pattern = "*{Foo,Bar}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K}_{grp,GRP}*"
```

Comma separated names within curly brackets mean OR, so it should resolve to 2 * 11 * 2 = 44 different wild card strings.

```
FooA_grp
FooB_GRP
BarA_grp
```

... and so on

How can I approach this with Python 2.7?

Comment: you can try to turn each group in "{}" expression into a list and do a nested loop for combination

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/533905/674039

Comment: Would you have a FooA_GRP?

Comment: Any reason for you’re using Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a cartesian product:

```
for item in itertools.product(*[['Foo', 'Bar'], ['A','B','C'], ['_'], ['grp', 'GRP']]):  
     print(''.join(item))
```

output:

```
FooA_grp
FooA_GRP
FooB_grp
FooB_GRP
FooC_grp
FooC_GRP
BarA_grp
BarA_GRP
BarB_grp
BarB_GRP
BarC_grp
BarC_GRP
```

Comment: You don't actually need `*[[]]` - `for a, b, c in itertools.product(['Foo', 'Bar'], 'ABC', ['grp', 'GRP']): print(a + b + '_' + c)` works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to create a possibility list from 3 list item, this will help you

```
li = ["Foo", "Bar"]
li2 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"]
li3 = ["grp", "GRP"]

possibility = []

for item in li2:
    p1 = li[0] + item + "_" + li3[0]
    p2 = li[0] + item + "_" + li3[1]
    p3 = li[1] + item + "_" + li3[0]
    p4 = li[1] + item + "_" + li3[1]

    possibility.append(p1)
    possibility.append(p2)
    possibility.append(p3)
    possibility.append(p4)
```

happy codding

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html); specifically [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
import itertools
list_a = ['Foo', 'Bar']
list_b = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"]
list_c = ["_"]
list_d = ["grp", "GRP"]
combinations = [''.join(element) for element in itertools.product(list_a, list_b, list_c, list_d)]
```

combinations

```
FooA_grp
FooA_GRP
FooB_grp
...
BarJ_GRP
BarK_grp
BarK_GRP
```

Additionaly, if you need to extract the lists `list_a`, `list_b`, `list_c`, and `list_d`, from the wildcard expression, you can use the [re](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) module

```
import re
exp = "*{Foo,Bar}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K}_{grp,GRP}*"
regex = r"\*{(.*)}{(.*)}(_){(.*)}\*"
matched_groups = re.match(regex, exp)
list_a = matched_groups.group(1).split(',')
list_b = matched_groups.group(2).split(',')
list_c = matched_groups.group(3).split(',')
list_d = matched_groups.group(4).split(',')
```

list_a

```
['Foo', 'Bar']
```

list_b

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
```

list_c

```
['_']
```

list_d

```
['grp', 'GRP']
```